# Program that prints all two-digit number combos with no repetition from certain digits

Tags: python

Can someone show me how to create a quick python program that prints all possible two digit number combos of the the digits: 1, 2, and 3. With no repetitions so no 11, 22, or 33.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what issues are you running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with condition (to exclude same digit cases).

```py
digits = [1, 2, 3]
output = [(x, y) for x in digits for y in digits if x != y]
print(output)
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

A more general and more handy way (suggested by Chris) is to use `itertools.permutation`:

```py
import itertools
output = list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3], 2))
```

Comment: Or just use `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: @Chris Oh you are right! I'll update the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,4):
     for k in range(1,4):
          if i!= k:
               print(str(i)+str(k))
```